Debug with Xcode while connecting a usb device to iPad Pro
We are developing a iPad accessory that connects to the USB-C port of an iPad Pro.
For debugging, we are using iPad pro M4 and iPad Pro 12.9 (fifth gen).
We are aware we can debug the app over wifi, but this process is slow and cumbersome.
Is there a USB-C hub ( I guess that supports thunderbolt because of this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410754/connecting-usb-c-ipad-pro-to-xcode-and-usb-peripheral ) that would allow us to connect the iPad to both our Mac and to the iPad accessory simultaneously ?
Thanks
